# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's exp

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, asynchronous, swipe

I am running into a really annoying issue. I added the following jQuery scripts to be able to use `swipeleft` and `swiperight` for a menu:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Now, whenever I click a url link within the menu, when I get to the destination page the style of the page is completley out of the format and the following warning shows up in the console.

```
jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

This is the code from `jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4`:

```
f(f.open(a.type,a.url,a.async,a.username,a.password),a.xhrFields)for(e
```

What can be wrong to where I click on a url and this issue arises? Before I added the jQuery scripts above this was not an issue. Also, if I reload a page that has the warning by reloading it in the browser, the page's format goes back to how it should be.

Any ideas?

If anyone would like to see this live, just comment below and I will put the link.

Comment: I don't have a answer to your issue but I'd recommend using the unminified JQuery libraries for development, they tend to be easier to debug.

Comment: @George What exactly are they? I normally use `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`, but this alone or even just this and the jquery.mobile will not allow the `swipeleft` to work.

Comment: Just remove the .min

Comment: @George That helped the format, but now I get this error that loads `Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity '16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA='. The resource has been blocked.`

Comment: I also don't think the swipe works anymore.

Comment: Is jQuery mobile the only jQuery script you have on your page?

Answer (score 1):

Use between libraries of jQuery and jquery.mobile like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```